# Is function composition associative in non-pure programming languages?

Tags: functional-programming, function, imperative-programming

We know that function composition is associative in theoretical programming languages such as STλC, and pure functional programming languages such as Haskell. Is the same true for languages where functions can mutate state and have all sorts of side effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, composition is still associative, but is not *function* composition anymore. Instead it is *morphism* composition in a Kleisli category of a monad that captures the computational effects. The nLab page on [monads in computer science](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monad+%28in+computer+science%29) describes the basic ideas and is probably a suitable starting point.